# asp.net FormView display ItemTemplate without databind and datasource

Tags: asp.net, formview, asprepeater

I have a FormView that has a repeater inside. In order to render the ItemTemplate I do a fake datasource and databind.
Then I look for the Repeater with FindControl and do another DataSource and DataBind.
So in this case HardCodedData is just a placehoder to get me to renter the FormView ItemTemplate.

```
FormView1.DataSource = HardCodedData;
FormView1.DataBind();

Repeater r = ((Repeater)FormView1.FindControl("repeater1"));
r.DataSource = GetMyData();
r.DataBind();
```

Is there a better way? Can I just get FormView to renter without giving it fake data? Or can I pass the repeater data through the FormView DataSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a repeater control is inside the form view than you should bind this repeater control inside the form view's event **DataBound** threw that you will be get exact data which you want to get. Put your following code inside your **FormView1_DataBound** event.

```
Repeater r = ((Repeater)FormView1.FindControl("repeater1"));
r.DataSource = GetMyData();
r.DataBind();
```

May be this solution can help you....

Comment: yes that works I can put the repeater in the form view's databound but I still need a way to get the FormView to renter its ItemTemplte. Withouth FormView1.DataSource = HardCodedData it still won't work because the Repeater won't be there. Any idea how I can get the ItemTemplate to render without faking it with fake data.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you do you want to do, so that will be easy to understand me your problem.

Comment: I used the DataBound as you suggested it works fine. The problem was with the code inside the repeater.